# MS Access TextBox Value is always NULL

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am doing some work for someone that insists on using MS Access. I don't usually use it so I am a bit new to the whole control structure and best practices. What I am trying to achieve is to have a filter textbox on a form which, when a value is entered, it will filter the rows in the detail section. That seems like a straightforward use case. I initially tried the following behaviour as the event handler for the On Change event:

```
Private Sub FilterGrid()
    Me.Text32.SetFocus

    If Not IsNull(Me.Text32.Text) And Me.Text32.Text <> "" Then
        Me.Filter = "JobNumber LIKE '*" & Me.Text32.Text & "*'"
        Me.FilterOn = True
    End
    Else
        Me.FilterOn = False
    End If
End Sub
```

This worked perfectly until I typed something that didn't have any rows matching and the whole thing exploded with this error (and was unrecoverable without closing the form):
Run-time error '2185': You can't reference a property or method for a control unless the control has the focus.

I did some reading around and the general opinion was that .Text should not be used and .Value (or simply the Text32 without a property) should be used. That produced some very strange behaviour. The `Text32.Value` is ALWAYS null. I have a watch window and I can see that for the normal behaviour, `Text32.Text` has an actual value, but `Text32.Value` is NULL.

Obviously I am doing something wrong, but I don't have enough experience with Access to know what it is.

Just as an aside, another suggestion was to do  `Text32.SetFocus` right before accessing the Text property. This doesn't resolve the error I mentioned. It still throws the exact same error.

Is anyone able to point me in the right direction here?

Comment: does `not = ""` produce the same behavior? or <> ""

Comment: Just another update. I have continued testing. It would seem that the Value property of the textbox is not updated until the control loses focus. I have tested the Value property on every event the control has registered and the only time it correctly displays what I have 'changed' in the text box is in the AfterUpdate event once I click somewhere besides that textbox. This would be easily solved then by adding a 'Search' button that has to be clicked, but I find that isn't a good user experience. It is much nicer if it filters as they type. (I know there's a performance concern).

Answer (score 4):

As you found out, the textbox's `Value` is only set after the control loses focus.
Conversely, the `Text` property is only accessible while the control has focus.

The `Value` property is defined as the default member for controls; that means `Text32` will be implicitly the same as `Text32.Value`, however, depending on the context,`Text32` can sometimes refer to the control itself, not just its value.

All these discrepancies can sometimes be infuriating.

To go back to the matter at hand: you have 2 ways to handle filtering.

- if the list to filter is large, it's probably better that the user type their filter, then press ENTER to validate it.
- if your list is not too large, you can implement filter as you type.

#### First case, wait for user input to be validated by ENTER.

Say your filtering textbox is called `txtFilter` and is located on a form whose subform is showing a datasheet (or continuous form) that you want to filter.

All you need to do is wire the textbox `OnKeyDown` events as such:

```
' We will only perform the filter if the user press the ENTER key
Private Sub txtFilter_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
    Select Case KeyCode
        Case 13, 9
            KeyCode = 0
            QuickFilter
    End Select
End Sub

' Perform the actual filtering on the subform
Private Sub QuickFilter()
    Dim sql As String
    Dim filter As String
    If txtFilter.Text = vbNullString Then
        ' Reset the filter if the textbox is emtpy
        SubForm.Form.FilterOn = False
    Else
        'Some common substitutions that users may have already inserted as wildchars
        filter = Replace(txtFilter.Text, "%", "*")
        filter = Replace("*" & filter & "*", "**", "*")
        ' We construct the filter SQL
        sql = "([JobNumber ] LIKE """ & filter & """)"
        sql = sql & " OR ([ProjectCode] LIKE """ & filter & """)"
        sql = sql & " OR ([SupplierName] LIKE """ & filter & """)"
        '... Add as many columns to filter on as you want

        ' Assign the filter to the subform
        SubForm.Form.filter = sql
        SubForm.Form.FilterOn = True
    End If
End Sub
```

#### Second case, filter as you type

Well, it's fairly easy, we just need to add to the above solution a way to track changes as the user is typing.
This is best done through the `OnChange` event of the texbox.

```
Private Sub txtFilter_Change()
    QuickFilter
End Sub
```

That's all you need to add.

Answer (score 0):

dont use .text property
instead use .value property

text3.value=text1.value+text2.value

you dont need setfocus like .text property everytime.

it works perfectly....vba ms access